# Quotient Scheme of a Proper Scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme proper over $\mathbb{Z}$, $G$ a finite group acting on $X$. Suppose that the quotient scheme $Y := X/G$ is well-defined.

Should $Y$ be then proper over $\mathbb{Z}$ as well?

Comment: By [Stacks 01W6](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01W6) this is equivalent to $Y$ separated. I know examples of nonseparated quotients when quotienting by a $\Bbb C^\times$ action but I can't remember right now whether this can happen or not when taking the quotient by a finite group.

Comment: I don't think this can go wrong when a finite group acts. For example if $X$ is a Hausdorff topological space and $G$ is a finite group acting on $X$, then the quotient space $X/G$ is automatically Hausdorff.